# Python Selenium Docker WebDriverwait throws timeOutException

Tags: python, docker, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I wrote a script for scraping a webpage. Even though my script is working on my local machine, when I dockerize the project, selenium throws an error due to WebDriverWait  Since I run the selenium in a conteiner, I couldn't find what is the reason of exception. I tried to use sleep, It waits on my computer but not in the container..

This is how I use WebDriverWait

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Basic Word Mark Search (New User)"))).click()
```

stack is :

```
File "main.py", line 67, in <module>
aws-scrapy-test  |     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Basic Word Mark Search (New User)"))).click()
aws-scrapy-test  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 89, in until
aws-scrapy-test  |     raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
aws-scrapy-test  | selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Tried those:

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Basic Word Mark Search (New User)")))
el.click()
```

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Basic Word Mark Search (New User)")))
el.click()
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you getting TimeoutException and wait doesn't help, I think the page, you're looking for is not loaded at all.

You should debug the behavior in docker. Before throwing error, e.g. add sleep 20 sec and:

- print current url
- take screenshot
- print the page source

So you'll understand more clearly what happened.

Browser could be redirected to some other page due to:

- https sertificate issue
- host unavailable issue
- some issue with ports, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the infos.
When I took the screenshot the current page, I realized that it is empty. As you said, the webpage might have some sertificate issues etc. 
I added some additional configs to my driver, and It worked :)

Comment: Hi @UgurKellecioglu could you please share what are the configurations that you added to driver?

Comment: @KrishanuChakraborty --ignore-certificate-errors should work